# How to draw this tab layout UI in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Does any one have idea how to do it in blackberry.

```
--------------------------------------
   tab 1        |     tab 2
---------------------------------------
 Content changes as per tab selection
---------------------------------------
 Content changes as per tab selection
---------------------------------------
 Content changes as per tab selection
--------------------------------------

List must displayed as per tab selection

--------------------------------------
```

Plz help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blackberry OS 6 introduced a new set of Pane Manager controls, one of which supports a tabbed mode.

Comment: ya i found that but still not understanding how to do it .i am totally new to blackberry

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?  The OS 6 SDK includes demos that you can view and run in Blackberry simulators.